# Why is VIM starting in replace mode?

Tags: linux, vim, conemu, vi

On several new CentOS 7 machines, I find that VIM automatically starts in replace mode.

After removing all automatically installed `.vimrc` files, normal behavior returns. However, if I simply create a `.vimrc` (eg. touch `~/.vimrc`), VIM will begin starting with replace mode enabled by default…

Comment: Not sure if this'll help, but it doesn't do that for me on a fresh CentOS 7.3 installation.

Comment: Thanks @mtak, that encouraged me to dig a little deeper.

Answer (score 36):

Seems to be an issue with utf-8 ambiguous characters and Windows cmd console. Flag t_u7 is set by default and so vim will request cursor position and get a bad reply from the ssh client.

Workaround: Adding `set t_u7=` or `set ambw=double` to your vimrc should fix the problem. `set t_u7=` will disable requesting cursor position and `ambw=double` will set the ambiguous characters mode to double.

For more info see vim reference manual: https://vimhelp.org/term.txt.html

Comment: `set ambw=double` appears to have conflict with airline/powerline characters. I see extra spaces after the <| arrows. `set t_u7=` works though!

Comment: I'm using Windows Terminal 1.2.2381 with Ubuntu 20.04.1 in WSL 1. This problem seemed to start spontaneously recently - perhaps something auto updated recently. Anyway, this fix resolved the problem.

Comment: As another commented mentioned, I am seeing this in Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS in WSL 1.

Comment: [@Zoran Bikicki](https://superuser.com/users/1139685/zoran-bikicki) Thanks a lot man! <3 This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 18):

I have just identified that the issue only occurs when connecting to the remote system using the native OpenSSH client released with Windows 10 1709 using the ConEmu terminal emulator. If I use the same client with native powershell or cmd there is no difficulty - appears to be an issue with ConEmu. Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Strangely enough I'm getting this behaviour on Windows 10 1709 using native cmd & /windows/system32/openssh/ssh client. I don't think I have ConEmu installed.

Comment: I am also seeing this when using the OpenSSH client available through Windows 10. I have ConEmu installed and see it there. But I also see it in standard PowerShell windows and the new Windows Terminal preview. It is unbelievably aggravating.

Comment: I was getting the same thing on Windows 10 1809 using the built-in SSH client to talk to a Synology NAS box running some flavour of Linux. Following the suggestion in [John Bolding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54464885/2096401) to a similar question, setting `TERM=screen-256color-s` seems to have worked (so far...!).